# Most suitable pipeline storage option for Jenkins/Kubernetes CI setup

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a quite complicated setup, considering that it's first time setting up such environment. I'm looking for some guidance on how to set it up properly.

I've got 7 servers, 2x28 CPU (for 112 threads total), 500GB RAM and 500GB HDD on each. All servers are connected into Proxmox VE cluster for easier management. On each server, I created one big VM with 100 cores, 300GB RAM and initially 40GB OS disk (smaller, faster backups in Proxmox, also I don't need to include container images and pipeline data in a backup). All VMs are running Ubuntu. I attached a second disk (300GB) to each VM and disabled it from backup.

Then I connected all VMs into Kubernetes cluster, in a multi master mode. All masters are connected into a load balancer.

Finally I connected my Kubernetes cloud to our corporate CloudBees Jenkins instance (through load balancer provided DNS name).

Till now, everything runs mostly smoothly, I'm able to execute jobs from Jenkins on my cluster.

Now I want to manage disk space somehow. I started with moving containerd root to second mounted HDD (300GB one) so my container images are stored there. As next step I also want for pipelines runtime data (whatever storage is needed by the containers to execute Jenkins job, including cloning ~2GB git repo) to be stored (temporarily) on that bigger disk.

Naturally, if I have 100 cores and 300GB of RAM, I want each of my k8s nodes to run multiple jobs at once, but right now, cloning repos for probably like 5-7 parallel jobs is already filling up the disk and basically makes node non-operational.

The issue is that Jenkins uses `/home/jenkins/agent` as default workspace in a pod and it mounts it in emptyDir and I haven't found how to override emptyDir initial location (seems like k8s just chooses what it likes). Let's say I'd like Jenkins pods' workspaces to be created as temporary directories under `/mnt/data/jenkins_workspace` (on host; it can of course still use `/home/jenkins/agent` inside the pod, I don't care).

I went through static and dynamic provisioning of Persistent Volumes, Claims and Storage Classes:

- hostPath which I looked at first, doesn't support multi-node cluster and it's not getting a dynamic name (multiple pods on each node).
- Static PV/PVC seem to limit me in terms of one per node, but it supports local as in providing a path where to create the temporary workspace for pod created dynamically by Jenkins.
- Dynamic provisioning doesn't support local, so I can't specify a path.
- There is CSI which I don't understand at all.
- I tried emptyDir.medium: "Memory" but it somehow hanged the pod and prevented git to even start cloning. I was running only a single job for a test, so there's no way it would run out of resources like that (I read that by default it reserves half of node's RAM).

One additional consideration here (inb4 "use nfs") - I already have 500GB HDD on each server and all of them will be used only for Jenkins CI/CD, I'd really prefer to use already present disks to manage job data.

From pipeline point of view, in my pod template yaml, I'm only defining one container that has all build tools, etc. Jnlp is provided by default.

Part of final pod yaml during job execution - only jnlp and base volumes, for brevity:

```
- name: "jnlp"
  env:
  - name: "JENKINS_AGENT_WORKDIR"
    value: "/home/jenkins/agent"
  volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: "/home/jenkins/agent"
    name: "workspace-volume"
    readOnly: false
volumes:
- emptyDir:
    medium: ""
  name: "workspace-volume"
```

What would you suggest or recommend in my situation? What would "make it work"? What would be the best approach here?